# Methods called before others are finished

Tags: ios, httprequest

In my project I have the following methods:

```
-(NSArray*)getWindSpeed
{
    [client setURL:@"windspeed"];
    NSLog(@"Wind speed asked");
    [client getData];
    return [self Parse];
}

-(NSArray *)Parse
{
    NSLog(@"parsing");
    return [parser parseJSONData:rawData];
}
```

When getWindSpeed is called, it first changes the url of the httpclient I've made and then asks for the data. In the client's getData method I do a httprequest and when it receives data it stores the data in an array. Then I want to return the parsed data. 
However, the Parse method is called before getData function of my client is finished.

So the rawData that the parser receives is always null.

I'm guessing this happens because [self Parse] is called before the client's

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

So..any tips on how I can make it so [self Parse] doesn't get called until data is received?

Comment: The call to getData is asynchronous so calling [self parse] just after it will not work as you said. Also as you hinted you should implement the delegate method didReceiveData and this is were you want to parse the data from the server.

Comment: @hugo exactly, but when I parse the data in didReceiveData, then return will be called before the parse so the problem remains.

Comment: Due to the nature of a synchronous requests you cannot have a method with the signature `- (NSArray*) getWindspeed` you will have to use something like `- (void) startWindSpeedRequest` and then use a delegate or target action to notify who ever is interseted in the windspeed after the data has loaded from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this the way you want. It's not possible (or at least it doesn't make sense) to return synchronously from an asynchronous operation/method/function.

You have to inherit the asynchronous, event-based model, i. e. don't try to return the parsed data, instead have the caller pass in a callback block that you call from within the `connection:didFinishLoading:` delegate method.

For example:

```
- (void)requestWindSpeedWithBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *))callback
{
    [client setURL:@"windspeed"];
    NSLog(@"Wind speed asked");
    [client loadData];

    dataAccumulator = [NSMutableData new];
    callbackBlock = callback;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [dataAccumulator appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    NSArray *array = [parser parseData:dataAccumulator];
    callbackBlock(array);
}
```

Also note the changed method names. **Don't prefix your method names with "get",** that naming convention implies a completely different usage.

Comment: I've used a delegate for now, but I'll certainly check this out later :) Also thanks for the tip about the name!